# Jmeter Summry report, Number of samples

Tags: jmeter, listener

I am simply hitting 10 URLs for 300 Virtual users but in Jmeter Summery report listener I see the only few URLs has 300 samples , for other URLs number of sample is getting down, like 250,197 and 150.

Could someone explain me why it happens?
Thanks in Advance.

Rupesh

Answer (score 0):

There could be various reasons for it.

- If You are using scheduler in ThreadGroup that finishes before all requests have processed, then the number of samples for initial requests could be higher
- If some of requests are dependent on success of other requests then it could also result in different no of samples for different requests

You can use Tree view listener to check details of your requests. Also try to identify which kind of requests have more samples. If you can find any pattern in it then that might help you narrow down the issue.